# How to replace an instance of array in Knockout while using datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, datatable

I have a table which populates from the JSON call below, for each call I am unable to replace the previous results and wondering why?(Using knockout js for binding and datatables on the ReportTable)

JS:

```
$.post("GetReport", { "Filter": ko.toJSON(Filter) }, function (data) {

            self.ReportTable([]);

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    self.ReportTable.push(data[i]);
            }

                $('#ReportsTable').DataTable(data);
               }, 'JSON');
```

It doesnt matter if I use self.ReportTable([]); or self.ReportTable.rmoveAll();the result set does come back but the datatables  crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out needed to add this code to re initialize the data tables properly

```
$.post("GetReport", { "ReportFilter": ko.toJSON(reportFilter) }, function (data) {
            $('#ReportsTable').DataTable().clear();
            $('#ReportsTable').DataTable().destroy();

            self.ReportTable.removeAll();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    self.ReportTable.push(data[i]);
            }
            $("#ReportsResult").show();

            $('#ReportsTable').DataTable(data);
            }, 'JSON');
        }
```

Comment: You should really have a custom binding handler for the DataTable.